# JavaScript populating and clearing <input> textbox

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I got 6 "textboxex" and an Array with them.
`<input id="slot0" type="text" />` id from 0 to 5, also Array named `"slotarray"`. I want arrray and textboxes to be bound `slotarray[0]` with `input id="slot0"` etc.

First i needed function that will find first empty field in array (no matter if corresponding textbox is empty - but should) and put there string (short string - shortcode like "abc" or "sp1").
This function also need to populate bound textbox with long string.
If `slotarray[2] == 'abc'` then  with the same number in ID (here be `id="slot2"`) need to contain long string like "Abrasive Brilliant Conexant".

Here what i got

```
<a href="#" onclick="populate('abc','Abrasive Brilliant Conexant');"> click to populate </a>
```

and then function

```
 function populate(shortstring,longstring) {
  for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    if (slotarray[i] == '') {
      slotarray[i] = shortsrting;
      slotid = 'slot' + i;
      document.getElementById(slotid).value = longstring;
      break;
     }
   }
 }
```

With clearing at the moment of creating: ( `Array('','','','','','')` ), and textbox `.value='';` its working as it should.

But then i figured out that i need function to clear textbox and bound array field. Not all but one specific for one clic. So instead of 6 functions i start to wrote

```
<a href="#" onclick="clear(0,'slot0');"> clear this field </a>
```

for each of textbox, with different numbers and ids ofcourse, and clearing function:

```
function clear(arrayid, slotid) {
  slotarray[arrayid] = '';
  document.getElementById(slotid).value = '';
}
```

But this function do not clearing textbox neither array. I see that textbox has text, and i know that array isn't cleared because first function works finding first empty object...

What am i doing wrong here? its definition of "empty"/"cleared" filed/textbox? maybe i need to use more complex conditions? maybe it is something else.
Maybe i don't need array (i can manage to get rid of short-codes) and just make functions work only on textboxes?

Ok - i prepared jsfiddle demo with this, but even populating don't work..

http://jsfiddle.net/BYt49/11/

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to demo it that will help to debug it easily

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? I would guess there could be an easier way to do this.

Comment: here you have: http://jsfiddle.net/BYt49/

Comment: Your code does not work for me on jsFiddle... I get an error about `ctb function is not defined`.  However, if I copy your HTML and JS locally, it works fine.  I'm assuming this is some sort of jsFiddle error.  Have you tried your code locally on your machine?  Also, I recommend using a debugger.

Comment: I write code locally from beggining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, whatever you have written is fine. `Just change to way` you call your javascript.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BYt49/20/

Comment: It's strange because i've changed function names in my final code and it wasnt working on the first time but when i run whole html file with firebug addon it suddenly start to working :)
I've changed also () brackets in array declaration to [] brackets, and place === in condition for searching empty slot.
I can say that topic is closed. Thank you Ashish, and thank you Valerio.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the keyword clear because refers to the (deprecated) function document.clear; so try to change the name of your "clear" function.

Comment: ok, i've changed function names. And still nothing.
http://jsfiddle.net/BYt49/11/
textboxes do not populate nor clear.
Maybe its about handling variable type?

Comment: it seems that jsfiddle loads the js in the window.onload function; in this way will not find your functions. I tried to move it in a <script> tag and it's work.